# Connect multiple 2 points with a line in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, point, line, table

I have a table in which each row has two columns representing the objectID of two different point features in the Map. There are thousands of such rows. How do I connect the each of these two points with a line?

I don't want the points of two different rows connected to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Use this tool [Points to Line (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003s000000). The "Line Field" option is where you would input the ObjectID that you want lines made for.

Comment: when i use that tool, I get an error, "Not enough points to create a line for value ##"

Comment: Yea I just noticed in your question the values were in 2 different columns. What you could do is copy the table, and join the two similar tables together. Add a single column for the LINE_ID, then calculate the values for each point into this new field. Use that field for the input

Comment: I think, this is still not the right way because I don't want the points of two different rows connected to each other with a line. I only want the two points of a row connected to each other.

Comment: Yea thats what im thinking. Each row has 2 values, you need those 2 values to be in 1 column. So for ObjectID 1 you have 2 columns of points. Copy your table and merge together, so now you have 2 copies of ObjectID 1. Create a new field, and for each ObjectID 1 (you have 2 now) calculate each value into the new field.

Comment: I still couldn't do it. Could you be more detailed in your instructions, please.